# Obtaining an isomorphism from a surjective homomorphism between abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism, free-abelian-group

Let $f: A\rightarrow B$ be a surjective homomorphism between abelian groups. I want to find such subgroup $B'\subset A$ that $\phi=f|_{B'}:B'\rightarrow B$ would be an isomorphism.

I think it's easy to get if $B$ is a free abelian group, you just need to find preimages $\{e'_i\}$ of all generators $\{e_i\}$, generate a subgroup and that would be $B'$, also $g(e_i)=e'_i$ would define the inverse.

But is it possible to get such $B'$ if $B$ is not free, using only surjectivity?

Comment: Every torsion group is a quotient of a torsionfree group; a nontrivial subgroup of a torsionfree group is torsionfree. No nontrivial torsion group is isomorphic to a torsionfree group. So if $B$ is torsion and $A$ is torsionfree, you will not be able to find $B'$, regardless of whether they are finitely generated or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible (generally).  Consider the natural map $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_2$.  This is surjective, but $\mathbb{Z}$ has no elements of order $2$ (or, equivalently, subgroups of order $2$).  I don't see how the non-finite-generation of $B$ could ever help.

Comment: Thank you for your counterexample. Well, I made a mistake in the last sentence, I wanted to write "if B is not free".

Comment: OK, then that works just fine, since my example had non-free codomain.